# How-to organize integration tests and unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Is it ok to have integration tests and unit tests in one assembly (project) ? Or rather have them separate ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I prefer to put them into separate assemblies. During continuous integration builds it is easier to distinguish between them because tools can be configured to execute all tests in a given assembly and you could for example want to run only unit tests or only integration tests which might take more time.

Comment: It's also useful conceptually, helping to keep straight in your head which type of test you're writing or running.

Comment: +1 for *"tools can be configured to execute all tests in a given assembly"*, especially with Jenkins CI & CD jobs.